# Show disclaimer site when opening external link

Tags: url, typo3, hook, typo3-extensions, typo3-7.6.x

I'm running a typo3 v. 7.6.4
I alredy looked into existing plugins an even how to write my own... but i can't find a solution.
My goal is pretty simple:
Show a simple disclaimer page whenever the user clicks a link to any external page.

Is there any easy ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please specify the process a little bit better? Would it be "enough" to add a class or a data-* attribute to all external links? Based on this you could implement an easy popup/ modal etc. with JavaScript.

Comment: @Björn The external links have to be "detected" automatically. The content alredy exists... and adding an attribute is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would in fact be to add a `on('click')` eventHandler on all links. This would be additional JavaScript and work with all existing content. Figuring out if a link refers to an external site should be easy (exclude relative urls and match absolute urls against your baseUrl).

However, if this is a legal requirement, you should decide if JavaScript works for you, because with disabled JS the disclaimer would not be triggered.